# assign variable to header.blade.php and return into content.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel

```
<!--in header.balde.php -->
$data = 'Hellow World'; // assigned a variable
{{ $data }} // echo hellow world // its working

//in content.blade.php
{{ $data }} // undefined variable it not comes on content // I have to must 
get variable data from header.blade.php

//Main Template.blade.php
@include('header')
@include('content')
@include('footer')
?>
```

I want to assign variable to header.blade.php and return into content.blade.php

Comment: your header is global right? i mean , are you including it in all .blade ??

Answer (score 1):

you can use session to store your data in this and use it anywhere in the project

```
Session::put('data', $data);
```

and use it in the blade as

```
Session::get('data');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass data in blade like this

```
public function example(){
    $data = 'hello world';
    return view('blade_template' compact('data'));
}
```

then in view just use `{{ $data }}` to print the value

Comment: I know. I can pass data from controller to every included blade. But i want to assign value into header blade and return to content blade

Comment: Well in that case you have to register a provider, this might help you https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-pass-variables-to-master-template